# Iphone - Why does stream cut the long messages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This is my code:

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
    if (theStream == inputStream) {
            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            long len;
            NSMutableString *total = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
            while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {
                    [total appendString: [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

                        currentOperation.response = total; 
                }
            }
            [super executeOperation:currentOperation];
    }
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? Im 100% certain the message is being sent correctly from my server. The problem disappear when I put a break point on the while loop if I disable the break point it cuts the message in several lines

Comment: Just try to print the message before and after the break point execution and see if there is any difference.

Comment: do your messages happen to be getting cut off after the `1024` characters you allocated for it in the buffer?  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by validating the JSON string and looping if it is not valid until it is valid

```
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: 
{

        if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[1024];

                long len;
                NSMutableString *totalJSONString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
                NSData *data;
                id json;
                do {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {
                        NSError *error = nil;
                        [totalJSONString appendString:[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                    }
                    data = [totalJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                } while (json == nil);
                currentOperation.response = totalJSONString;
                NSLog(@"%@", totalJSONString);
                totalJSONString = (NSMutableString *) @"";
                [super executeOperation:currentOperation];

        }
        break;
    }
```